# Date diff in sequlize js

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a table called events.

`events(id,event_date)`

I want to get the events where 
**event_date - current_date() = 7**

how do I achieve this using sequlize.js?

Comment: It might help to know which relational database is being used, i.e. PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc....

Answer (score 0):

you can query using sequelize raw query

```
sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM public.events WHERE DATE_PART('day',  event_date-NOW())=7;`)
```